# Can twitter api notify my app if some @username gets mentioned?

Tags: twitter

Can twitter api notify my app if for example some @username gets mentioned (push like), instead of checking every 
minute if a username/usernames are mentioned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use the [Twitter Streaming APIs](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview)

> The Twitter Streaming API allows
>   high-throughput near-realtime access
>   to various subsets of public and
>   protected Twitter data.

Comment: Just remember that you will not receive any tweets that occurred while you were disconnected from the streaming endpoint.  You'll need to backfill any missed tweets using either the search or REST APIs.

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet supported by the API. There are 3rd-party APIs that can do this though. I used [Imified](http://www.imified.com/) before to do just this, they support Twitter mentions as well as IM networks like GTalk.